# beginner confusion regarding roles with postgres

Tags: postgresql

Let's take a simple example of what I'd like to achieve:

Create a schema 'accounts' and add two tables like 'users' and 'api_credentials'.

```
CREATE SCHEMA accounts
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts.users ()
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts.api_credentials ()
;
```

Now, I'd like to create a role 'admin' and have it have r/w access to any tables within that schema:

```
CREATE ROLE administrator;
ALTER SCHEMA accounts OWNER TO administrator;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA accounts TO administrator;
```

is this the correct way to do it?

And then I'd like to create a 'viewer' role that can only read:

```
CREATE ROLE reader;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA accounts TO reader;
.. and how do I make this read only?
```

And what is the role of this:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydatabase TO myrole
```

I've seen in in the docs, but I'm unsure; does that mean that a user with that role can't login? I thought the login permissions were with the users?
(I'd like several users to inherit that role)

Comment: No, you need to give specific read/write permissions on the tables. Granting access or owner rights to the schema is not enough.

Comment: how does it work for 'future' tables in that schema then?

Comment: The role that runs the `CREATE` statement always owns the object (e.g. the table). Additional [privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) to other roles are automatically granted from the default privileges, you use [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) to manage those for future tables.